# Is there a way to remove wrong answers?

Tags: discussion

Some questions can be answered objectively, so the answers are either right, or wrong.
[In this case](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5580/) 3 are wrong, and mine is right. 
The votes do not reflect this however, you have to read all answers carefully to realize this.

I have downvoted all other answers, what else can I do?

Comment: No - because the community determines who's wrong.  Usually the person who wants others' answers removed is not necessarily in the right. If you are really right, your answer will rise to the top - by definition, if it's not, the other experts on this site don't consider it the most right.

Comment: @mxyzplk You ought to make that into an answer since it effectively is one. I'd vote for it - you've expressed fairly concisely my own thoughts on the matter.

Comment: @doppelgreener done!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you believe that upvoted or accepted answers to a question are wrong (or perhaps outdated, as the answers to the linked question are all over two years old), you can do several things:

- You can downvote them, an option you've already explored.
- You can comment on them, explaining why you believe them to be wrong or outdated. The user who wrote the answer will be automatically notified of your comment, and if convinced, will modify or remove their answers.
- You can go on Chat and attempt to convince people that these answers are wrong, and should be downvoted. Downvoting is the primary mechanism on StackExchange to differentiate wrong answers from right, and if those answers really are wrong, many on the site will be glad to improve the quality of answers provided, and downvote the incorrect answers.
- If you believe the accepted answer is wrong, you can comment on the original question, or on the wrong answer while @mentioning the original asker, urging him to reconsider and trying to explain why he's chosen a wrong answer.
- What you *shouldn't* do is Flag the answers for moderator attention. Moderators are not arbiters of correct or incorrect *content*. Moderators keep the site running, erase spam and abusive content, deal with malcontents, and in general (to quote the FAQ) "are there to deal with those exceptional conditions that could otherwise disrupt the community". They can't, and *shouldn't* erase content that is *wrong*. That is the community's job.

All of these actions should, of course, be taken in a polite and reasoned manner. Going around shouting "I'm right, you're wrong" won't win you any points in getting your message across. Our goal here is to have good answers to good questions. If you an just convince an answerer to fix his "almost true but slightly wrong or out of date" answer, especially to a two year old question, you'll probably be doing the site the biggest service.

Comment: Well, this did not go as well as planned, I just lost those 2 upvotes I had.

Comment: @András part of the problem is that your answer, while it might be right, doesn't address the problem presented in the question very directly, and it doesn't explain why and how the presented feats are relevant to your rules citation. If you're answer is going to overtake better answers it needs to *be* a better answer. It's also relatively redundant with Oblivious Sage's answer from a month before yours, show how yours is different.

Comment: @waxeagle Oblivious Sage states that the rules allow more than 4 feats to affect an at-will, the number is actually 2.

Comment: *"Going around shouting "I'm right, you're wrong" won't win you any points in getting your message across."* Yeah, we tried that method out for a while, it didn't work out well. :>

Comment: @András Actually I'm the only person upvoting you on that answer now.

Comment: Minor nitpick: @pinging the OP in an answer comment will only work if they've also commented on ([or edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020)) the same answer. Commenting on the question will always notify the OP, though.

Answer (score 9):

No - because the community determines who's right and who's wrong. Usually the person who wants others' answers removed is not necessarily in the right. If you are really right, your answer will rise to the top - by definition, if it doesn't, the other experts on this site don't consider it the most right.  Everyone who posts an answer thinks they're right and others are wrong, but here we use the democratic method to determine objective truth.

lisardggY points out the other recourses available to you, but of course, as you've discovered, it's still subject to the larger community's opinion on the subject.